# Props in React functional component not covered with jest

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I have been trying to test a react functional component using jest and enzyme. In the coverage results the props passed to the components are not covered and shows as **statement not covered**. Is there a way to cover the props passed to the component. Please guide.

the functional component:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Popover, Button } from '@patternfly/react-core';
import {
  handleSkip,
  handleRetry,
  stateIconCreator
} from '../../../utils/Utils';
import { ProcessInstance } from '../../../graphql/types';
interface IOwnProps {
  processInstanceData: ProcessInstance;
  setModalTitle: (modalTitle: string) => void;
  setTitleType: (titleType: string) => void;
  setModalContent: (modalContent: string) => void;
  handleRetryModalToggle: () => void;
  handleSkipModalToggle: () => void;
}
const ErrorPopover: React.FC<IOwnProps> = ({
  processInstanceData,
  setModalTitle,
  setTitleType,
  setModalContent,
  handleRetryModalToggle,
  handleSkipModalToggle
}) => {
  return (
    <Popover
      zIndex={300}
      headerContent={<div>Process error</div>}
      bodyContent={
        <div>
          {processInstanceData.error
            ? processInstanceData.error.message
            : 'No error message found'}
        </div>
      }
      footerContent={
        processInstanceData.addons.includes('process-management') &&
        processInstanceData.serviceUrl && [
          <Button
            key="confirm1"
            variant="secondary"
            onClick={() =>
              handleSkip(
                processInstanceData,
                setModalTitle,
                setTitleType,
                setModalContent,
                handleSkipModalToggle
              )
            }
            className="pf-u-mr-sm"
          >
            Skip
          </Button>,
          <Button
            key="confirm2"
            variant="secondary"
            onClick={() =>
              handleRetry(
                processInstanceData,
                setModalTitle,
                setTitleType,
                setModalContent,
                handleRetryModalToggle
              )
            }
            className="pf-u-mr-sm"
          >
            Retry
          </Button>
        ]
      }
      position="auto"
    >
      <Button variant="link" isInline>
        {stateIconCreator(processInstanceData.state)}
      </Button>
    </Popover>
  );
};

export default ErrorPopover;
```

I am doing a snapshot test :

```
import React from 'react';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import ErrorPopoverComponent from '../ErrorPopoverComponent';
import { ProcessInstanceState } from '../../../../graphql/types';

const props = {
  processInstanceData: {
    id: 'e4448857-fa0c-403b-ad69-f0a353458b9d',
    processId: 'travels',
    businessKey: 'T1234',
    parentProcessInstanceId: null,
    parentProcessInstance: null,
    processName: 'travels',
    roles: [],
    state: ProcessInstanceState.Error,
    rootProcessInstanceId: null,
    addons: ['jobs-management', 'prometheus-monitoring', 'process-management'],
    start: '2019-10-22T03:40:44.089Z',
    end: '2019-10-22T05:40:44.089Z',
    lastUpdate: '2019-10-22T03:40:44.089Z',
    error: {
      nodeDefinitionId: '_2140F05A-364F-40B3-BB7B-B12927065DF8',
      message: 'Something went wrong'
    },
    serviceUrl: null,
    endpoint: 'http://localhost:4000',
    variables:
      '{"flight":{"arrival":"2019-10-30T22:00:00Z[UTC]","departure":"2019-10-22T22:00:00Z[UTC]","flightNumber":"MX555"},"trip":{"begin":"2019-10-22T22:00:00Z[UTC]","city":"Bangalore","country":"India","end":"2019-10-30T22:00:00Z[UTC]","visaRequired":false},"hotel":{"address":{"city":"Bangalore","country":"India","street":"street","zipCode":"12345"},"bookingNumber":"XX-012345","name":"Perfect hotel","phone":"09876543"},"traveller":{"address":{"city":"Bangalore","country":"US","street":"Bangalore","zipCode":"560093"},"email":"ajaganat@redhat.com","firstName":"Ajay","lastName":"Jaganathan","nationality":"US"}}',
    nodes: [
      {
        nodeId: '1',
        name: 'End Event 1',
        definitionId: 'EndEvent_1',
        id: '870bdda0-be04-4e59-bb0b-f9b665eaacc9',
        enter: '2019-10-22T03:37:38.586Z',
        exit: '2019-10-22T03:37:38.586Z',
        type: 'EndNode'
      },
      {
        nodeId: '2',
        name: 'Confirm travel',
        definitionId: 'UserTask_2',
        id: '6b4a4fe9-4aab-4e8c-bb79-27b8b6b88d1f',
        enter: '2019-10-22T03:37:30.807Z',
        exit: '2019-10-22T03:37:38.586Z',
        type: 'HumanTaskNode'
      },
      {
        nodeId: '3',
        name: 'Book Hotel',
        definitionId: 'CallActivity_1',
        id: 'dd33de7c-c39c-484a-83a8-3e1b007fce95',
        enter: '2019-10-22T03:37:30.793Z',
        exit: '2019-10-22T03:37:30.803Z',
        type: 'SubProcessNode'
      },
      {
        nodeId: '4',
        name: 'Join',
        definitionId: '_2140F05A-364F-40B3-BB7B-B12927065DF8',
        id: '08c153e8-2766-4675-81f7-29943efdf411',
        enter: '2019-10-22T03:37:30.806Z',
        exit: '2019-10-22T03:37:30.807Z',
        type: 'Join'
      },
      {
        nodeId: '4',
        name: 'Book Flight',
        definitionId: 'CallActivity_2',
        id: '683cf307-f082-4a8e-9c85-d5a11b13903a',
        enter: '2019-10-22T03:37:30.803Z',
        exit: '2019-10-22T03:37:30.806Z',
        type: 'SubProcessNode'
      },
      {
        nodeId: '5',
        name: 'Book',
        definitionId: 'ParallelGateway_1',
        id: 'cf057e58-4113-46c0-be13-6de42ea8377e',
        enter: '2019-10-22T03:37:30.792Z',
        exit: '2019-10-22T03:37:30.803Z',
        type: 'Split'
      },
      {
        nodeId: '6',
        name: 'Join',
        definitionId: 'ExclusiveGateway_2',
        id: '415a52c0-dc1f-4a93-9238-862dc8072262',
        enter: '2019-10-22T03:37:30.792Z',
        exit: '2019-10-22T03:37:30.792Z',
        type: 'Join'
      },
      {
        nodeId: '7',
        name: 'is visa required',
        definitionId: 'ExclusiveGateway_1',
        id: '52d64298-3f28-4aba-a812-dba4077c9665',
        enter: '2019-10-22T03:37:30.79Z',
        exit: '2019-10-22T03:37:30.792Z',
        type: 'Split'
      },
      {
        nodeId: '8',
        name: 'Visa check',
        definitionId: 'BusinessRuleTask_1',
        id: '6fdee287-08f6-49c2-af2d-2d125ba76ab7',
        enter: '2019-10-22T03:37:30.755Z',
        exit: '2019-10-22T03:37:30.79Z',
        type: 'RuleSetNode'
      },
      {
        nodeId: '9',
        name: 'StartProcess',
        definitionId: 'StartEvent_1',
        id: 'd98c1762-9d3c-4228-9ffc-bc3f423079c0',
        enter: '2019-10-22T03:37:30.753Z',
        exit: '2019-10-22T03:37:30.754Z',
        type: 'StartNode'
      }
    ],
    childProcessInstances: []
  },
  setModalTitle: jest.fn(),
  setTitleType: jest.fn(),
  setModalContent: jest.fn(),
  handleRetryModalToggle: jest.fn(),
  handleSkipModalToggle: jest.fn()
};
describe('Errorpopover component tests', () => {
  it('snapshot testing', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<ErrorPopoverComponent {...props} />);
    expect(wrapper).toMatchSnapshot();
  });
});
```

[image: coverage-report-errorpopover]

Comment: You pretty much just need to have a test (or more) that passes the missing props. For the snapshot what props are being passed?

Comment: I have added the entire test file. I am passing all the required props but still getting the statement not covered

Comment: Shallow (versus mount) mounting doesn't render children, so it could just be that those props aren't getting used and thus no coverage on them. What's the coverage of the rest of `ErrorPopover`?

Comment: even after changing to `mount` I am not getting the coverage. I have attached the screenshot of the coverage.

Comment: one point to note is that the `<popover>` is provided by a third party library.